# Javascript / jQueryで高速なTable表示ライブラリを探しています

Tags: javascript, jquery

6 Column x 400 Row のテーブルで、Ajaxにてデータを2秒周期で更新しようとしています。一度に更新を行う数は不定ですが、3 Column x 50 Row 程度が平均かと思います。waTableを使って実装していましたが、DataBindを使っても更新が遅く、徐々にAjaxの発行周期も遅くなってしまいます。

現在、更新方法の見直しをしていますが、他にオススメのライブラリが有れば教えて頂きたいです。

- 表の各Rowにチェックボックスが有ればベストですが、無くても可能
- Ajaxにて動的にデータ書き換えが可能
- 出来ればソート可能

の条件でオススメを教えて下さい。

Answer (score 1):

全然回答になっていなくて恐縮ですが、Demo付きでいろいろ紹介しているサイトがあったので。
[jQuery Tables Plugin & Tutorials with Example](http://www.jqueryrain.com/example/jquery-tables/)

あとは紹介サイトを少し。
[New jQuery Table Plugins To Organize Your Data – 21 Items](http://www.designyourway.net/drb/new-jquery-tables-plugins-to-organize-your-data-21-items/)
[35 Amazing jQuery Tables](http://www.sitepoint.com/30-amazing-jquery-tables/) ※古いです（2011年）

Comment: 参考にさせて頂きます。
自身の調査でSlickGridというのを見つけたので、それと合わせて検討したいと思います。
有難う御座いました